# removeData causing the value to revert to the value of

Tags: jquery

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/), .removeData() will cause the value of the property being removed to revert to the value of the data attribute of the same name in the DOM.

Q: What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this (initial) HTML source code:

```
<div data-x="1"></div>
```

Consider this code:

```
div.data('x'); // returns 1

div.data('x', 2);

div.data('x'); // returns 2

div.removeData('x');

div.data('x'); // returns 1
```

(where `div` refers to the DIV object in the DOM.)

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DyGBB/

So, `data('x')` will initially return the value of the `data-x` HTML attribute of that DIV. However, if you programmatically set this same data-property like so: `data('x', 2)`, then `data('x')` no longer returns the value of the `data-x` HTML attribute, but the value that you stored using `data('x', ...)`.

If you now execute `removeData('x')`, the programmatically set value will be deleted, so that `data('x')` will once again return the value of the `data-x` HTML attribute.

Note that "HTML attributes" don't actually exist anymore once the page has loaded and the DOM has been built. However, DOM elements contain an `attributes` property which is an object that contains a corresponding property for each HTML attribute which was defined on the HTML element in the HTML source code.

Comment: Wow.  Who knew?  That's really odd.

Answer (score 1):

If your object corresponds to the following html element:

<div data-attname="some value"></div>

then the property of the javascript object called "attname" will revert to "some value" from whatever you had it set to.